# Why .click function of jQuery is updating everything in document on second click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery in my web site. Following is the code i am getting problem with:

```
 $("#activitiesbtn").click(function(){
    $('#dashboard-mainsubhead').load('activity.html', function() {
        // doing some stuff here

        // Following code is making problem
        $('.subareas').bind('click', function(){
            var keytext = $(this).find('.areakey').text();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/getactivity',
                data: {activitykey: keytext},
                success: function(result) { 
                    activityobj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                }
            });

            var activityurl = activityobj.mapurl;
            var activmapurl = "<img src=\""+activityurl+"\"></img>";
            $('#activity-mapimg').html(activmapurl);
            $('#activity-activitykey').html(activityobj.key);
            $('#activity-activitymode').html(activityobj.activityMode);
            $('#activity-time').html(activityobj.totalTimeTaken);
            $('#activity-distance').html(activityobj.totalDistanceCovered);
            $('#activity-calories').html(activityobj.calories);
            $('#activity-wallutas').html(activityobj.wallutas);

            alert("subarea div clicked");
        });
    });
});
```

problem is that first time when i click any of div which has subareas class, nothing happens. But after that every time when i click any subareas class div, alert "subarea div clicked" comes but text of other divs changes on every second click. Why is it happening? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you try to click before the content is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to unbind the `click` every time otherwise the code will execute multiple times.

Second, you need to use the data returned by the `.ajax` call only in the success event:

```
$('.subareas').unbind("click");
$('.subareas').bind('click', function(){
    var keytext = $(this).find('.areakey').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/getactivity',
        data: {activitykey: keytext},
        success: function(result) { 
            activityobj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            var activityurl = activityobj.mapurl;
            var activmapurl = "<img src=\""+activityurl+"\"></img>";
            $('#activity-mapimg').html(activmapurl);
            $('#activity-activitykey').html(activityobj.key);
            $('#activity-activitymode').html(activityobj.activityMode);
            $('#activity-time').html(activityobj.totalTimeTaken);
            $('#activity-distance').html(activityobj.totalDistanceCovered);
            $('#activity-calories').html(activityobj.calories);
            $('#activity-wallutas').html(activityobj.wallutas);
        }
    });
});
```

The variable `activityobj` won't have any value outside the `$.ajax()` function the first time it executes - the second time it has the value of the previous call.

Answer (score 0):

Your second listener which is `$('.subareas') click` inside first click listener

for activating it you need to click `$("#activitiesbtn")`

You need to move  `$('.subareas') click listener` to out of first listener.

```
 $("#activitiesbtn").click(function(){
    $('#dashboard-mainsubhead').load('activity.html', function() {
        // doing some stuff here

    });
});


// Following code is making problem
$('.subareas').bind('click', function(){
    var keytext = $(this).find('.areakey').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/getactivity',
        data: {activitykey: keytext},
        success: function(result) { 
            activityobj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        }
    });

    var activityurl = activityobj.mapurl;
    var activmapurl = "<img src=\""+activityurl+"\"></img>";
    $('#activity-mapimg').html(activmapurl);
    $('#activity-activitykey').html(activityobj.key);
    $('#activity-activitymode').html(activityobj.activityMode);
    $('#activity-time').html(activityobj.totalTimeTaken);
    $('#activity-distance').html(activityobj.totalDistanceCovered);
    $('#activity-calories').html(activityobj.calories);
    $('#activity-wallutas').html(activityobj.wallutas);

    alert("subarea div clicked");
});
```